# Get a list of all of an Azure Function App's functions & status

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

With Azure Powershell, how do you get a list of all of a Function App's functions and their respective status (status at the function level, not FunctionApp level)?

I can get a list of FunctionApps with

```
Get-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName my-resource-group-name
```

which will give me the FunctionApps and it's FunctionApp.Status but cannot then iterate
through these FunctionApps to find a list of each of their functions and the status of those functions.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try below solution ? If yes do share the feedback in comment or mark the answer as helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could get one half of the answer (will update the answer, if I get the status of function)

```
$ResourceGroupName = "RGNAME"
$AppName = "FUNCTIONAPPNAME" 

(Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $AppName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions").ResourceName
```

[image]

**Update** : Getting status also of function

```
$ResourceGroupName = "RGNAME"
$AppName = "FUNCTIONAPPNAME"
Get-AzResource -ApiVersion "2022-03-01" -Name $AppName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/" -ExpandProperties | ConvertTo-Json
```

Now you get an array of functions. Have a close look at the output. See the green boxes to help you out with the name and status as shown in the reference screenshot

[image]

Hope it helps !

Comment: Absolutely spot on, I'd never seen that ApiVersion flag, it seems to open up a lot of additional data. Thanks